# Why encrypt client<->server on top of TLS?

Tags: encryption, tls

I want to implement TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 between my client and my server.

However, someone advices me to add my own encryption&digital signature on top of it (adding a suite of diffie hellmnan,AES,elliptic curves,...) - basically, another TLS over TLS...

Does that make any sense? Isn't TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 sufficient and safe enough?

Comment: Yes, I saw this post. However, 2 years later, the answer seems still unclear... Is TLS enough?

Comment: As the first answer there notes, it depends on your situation.